# Cannot login to owncloud. No space left on device

Tags: linux, owncloud

I am currently using the last version of owncloud. Since the installation, I cannot login anymore. A quick look at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` explains why :

```
WARNING:  could not create relation-cache initialization file "global/pg_internal.init.7826": No space left on device
DETAIL:  Continuing anyway, but there's something wrong.
WARNING:  could not create relation-cache initialization file "base/17999/pg_internal.init.7826": No space left on device
DETAIL:  Continuing anyway, but there's something wrong.
WARNING:  could not create relation-cache initialization file "global/pg_internal.init.7827": No space left on device
DETAIL:  Continuing anyway, but there's something wrong.
WARNING:  could not create relation-cache initialization file "base/17999/pg_internal.init.7827": No space left on device
DETAIL:  Continuing anyway, but there's something wrong.
WARNING:  could not create relation-cache initialization file "global/pg_internal.init.7828": No space left on device
```

But I cannot figure *where* I do not have enough space. If I try `df -h` as `root`, everything seems ok to me :

```
:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G   20G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G   82M  3.8G   3% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2       898G  912M  851G   1% /home
tmpfs           788M     0  788M   0% /run/user/0
```

Excepted the first line which I hardly understand what it represents. I installed owncloud into /home/owncloud so I bet everything should be ok.

Any idea?

Edit :

Results of findmnt :

```
~# findmnt /
TARGET SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      /dev/sda1 ext4   rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
~# findmnt /dev/sda1
TARGET SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      /dev/sda1 ext4   rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
~# findmnt /dev/sda2
TARGET SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/home  /dev/sda2 ext4   rw,relatime,data=ordered
```

Comment: Your root filesystem `/` is full. I suspect you will have a lot of other problems soon if this is not fixed.

Comment: @drescherjm I found that `/dev/root` is `/dev/sda1`. Is there a way to know if both `/dev/root` and `/dev/sda2` are physically on the same drive. If there aren't, do I still have a chance to resize `/dev/root`?

Comment: type `sudo findmnt /`

Comment: You may want to try deleting large files in /var/log

Comment: `/var/log# du -h` -> `14G ./jenkins`. I think I found the culprit XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, these programs store their data under `/var`, In your case, you don't have a separate mountpoint for `/var` so it's a directory on your root file system `/`. This is full and so the program is not working.

Before you attempt a resize or anything, I think you should find out what is hogging 20GB. `du / | sort -n` should give you a rough idea of the guilty parties or you can use a graphical tool like xdiskusage. Clean it up and you'll be good to go.

The other alternative is to look through the config files for owncloud and make it use your home directory to store its data. That way, it will work. But you should clean up your `/`. Various things will misbehave if you don't.

Comment: Jenkins logs were indeed taking 14Gb on the 20Gb in `/`. I archived and delete them from `/var/log`. It solved the issue. It might be a good idea to have a separate partition for `/var/log/`.

Comment: It definitely would be.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are out of inodes: [No space left on device – running out of Inodes](http://www.ivankuznetsov.com/2010/02/no-space-left-on-device-running-out-of-inodes.html).

Use `df -i` to check that. It happened to me as my backup used to have millions of small files. So there was space left but no inodes left.

Comment: It did not solve the problem but I learnt something. Moreover, it can help a future googler.